# Heart signal chart in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a application to draw hear signal chart as figure. Could you suggest to me how to implement it in android (that means which is layout in this case). Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom `View` in which you will override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. In this method you can use a `canvas` object to draw lines and other shapes in order to get the result you want. Take a look at methods `drawLine(...)` , `drawPath(...)`.

EDIT:

```
class HeartGraphView extends View {
    float[] dataX, dataY;

    @Override 
    public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            // apply some transformation on data in order to map it correctly
            // in the coordinates of the canvas
            canvas.drawLine(dataX[i], dataY[i], dataX[i+1], dataY[i+1] ... );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you show to me the code. I did not use Canvas. I assume I have a array signal that are var myPoints = [1,2, 10,20, 30,40 ]; //here 3 points: x1,y2, x2,y2, x3,y3

Comment: Thank you. I think your code must edit something in drawLine function, I use canvas.drawLine(dataX[i], dataY[i], dataX[i+1], dataY[i+1],paint); It works now. And I have a small question. Let see above figure. How to control the position of chart in the figure. I use your code. It auto set in top-right of screen. I want to set same postion as the figure

Answer (score 3):

use **[achartengine library](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list)** and u can eaisly set up the design as u have mentioned above  and manipulate your data accordingly and for more details [GO TO](http://jaxenter.com/effort-free-graphs-on-android-with-achartengine-46199.html) and can be manipulated dynamically through custom list adapter

Hope it Help You